# Hadoop JAR: "JobTracker is in safe mode"

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to run the Wordcount example and I got this thrown at my face:

```
13/12/01 19:46:49 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
as:player cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SafeModeException: JobTracker is in safe mode
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkSafeMode(JobTracker.java:5188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getStagingAreaDir(JobTracker.java:3677)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SafeModeException: JobTracker is in safe mode
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.checkSafeMode(JobTracker.java:5188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getStagingAreaDir(JobTracker.java:3677)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getStagingAreaDir(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy2.getStagingAreaDir(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getStagingAreaDir(JobClient.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

I've tried a few configurations in `mapred-default.xml`, but without success.

Comment: Go check the logs for your Job Tracker, are there any exception stack traces as to why it's in safe mode? Do you have any Task Trackers connected, what version of hadoop are you running, ....

Comment: jobtracker usually goes to safemode if its not able to access the {hadoop.tmp.dir}. Check if the dir is there and you have permissions on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HDFS was unavailable. The logs were stating that a certain directory was damaged, rendering it unreadable. I had to shut down the NameNode, format it with `hadoop namenode -format`, and restart it.

Answer (score 4):

Try issuing command

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

If successful you may get "Safe mode is OFF"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the file `/dfs/name/in_use.lock` in the `hadoop.tmp.dir`. This solution is little less invasive than formatting the `NameNode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

This command has helped a lot. Problem resolved by turning off the safemode.